# Can I create a root site immediately under a wildcard managed path?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, site, path, managed-path

We setup a wildcard managed path `/projects` in our web application.

Is it possible to setup a root site for `http://www.abc.be/projects`?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can't create a SharePoint site directly under the **wildcard** managed path. Managed paths cannot be both explicit and wildcard at the same time.

You can <strike>make the root `/projects` an **explicit** inclusion and create a few **explicit** project site collections beneath it</strike>, but that's not recommended.

As an alternative, you could create a default `/projects/index` or `/projects/portfolio` site and configure a redirection from `/projects` to the default site in IIS, but that's also an administrative overhead. Consider the pros and cons and decide for your organisation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, though not recommended.  I did this on a SP 2013 site that is currently in use and has been for a few years.  Though I won't post all of the article here as it is long and explanatory, this article is what I followed:

[How to: Create a Site Collection at the root level of your Web Application](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/09/22/how-to-create-a-site-collection-at-the-root-level-of-your-web-application.aspx)

The main thing to remember is if you can take a backup of the system (easy if it is virtualized) that is best in case you mess something up (see the comments in the article).  Also do it after hours because if I remember correctly, it takes down all the sites.  This is because you are modifying the root element.

Here are the steps for doing it:

1. Go to the SP Central Administration page
2. Click on Manage web applications
3. Select your web application by name by clicking on it.
4. Click the managed paths at the top of the page.
5. Delete the (root) path.
6. Add a new (root) path "/".  Select Wildcard inclusion.
7. Add your new site collection normally.  Remeber the NAME
8. Go back to managed paths and delete the (root) path.
9. Add a new (root) path "/".  Select Type Explicit inclusion.
10. Add a new path for your site collection NAME. Select Type Explicit inclusion.

Good luck!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

When going to create the site collection from Central Administration you can create the managed path with the a site collection by applying the setting 'Explicit Inclusion'.

Details can be found here.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc261845.aspx

Comment: You can use **either** wildcard **or** explicit, **not both** for the same path. Root is an exception.

Comment: if you correct your answer, I'll remove the downvote and maybe you'll gain reputation by getting the answer accepted and voted up later on.